# How do I automate Excel from an HTML Web page by using JScript?

Tags: html, excel, vba, jscript

According to Microsoft:

[How to automate Excel from an HTML Web page by using JScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-excel-using-jscript)

Summary
This article demonstrates how to create and manipulate a Microsoft Office Excel workbook from an HTML page.

More Information
This article illustrates JScript code that automates Excel. JScript has no internal means of creating SAFEARRAYs. When using automation, if you call a function that requires a SAFEARRAY, you can use VBScript to create the SAFEARRAY. The code below demonstrates this combination of JScript and VBScript code.

Building the automation sample
Start Notepad.

Paste the following code into Notepad.

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
Press the button to start Excel and display quarterly data.
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
Function CreateNamesArray()
' Create an array to set multiple values at once.
  Dim saNames(5, 2)
  saNames(0, 0) = "John"

saNames(0, 1) = "Smith"
  saNames(1, 0) = "Tom"
  saNames(1, 1) = "Brown"
  saNames(2, 0) = "Sue"
  saNames(2, 1) = "Thomas"
  saNames(3, 0) = "Jane"
  saNames(3, 1) = "Jones"
  saNames(4, 0) = "Adam"
  saNames(4, 1) = "Johnson"
  CreateNamesArray = saNames
End Function
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JScript"> 
function AutomateExcel()
{

// Start Excel and get Application object.
      var oXL = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");

oXL.Visible = true;

// Get a new workbook.
      var oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add();
      var oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet;

// Add table headers going cell by cell.
      oSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "First Name";
      oSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Last Name";
      oSheet.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Full Name";
      oSheet.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Salary";

// Format A1:D1 as bold, vertical alignment = center.
      oSheet.Range("A1", "D1").Font.Bold = true;
      oSheet.Range("A1", "D1").VerticalAlignment =  -4108; //xlVAlignCenter

// Create an array to set multiple values at once.

// Fill A2:B6 with an array of values (from VBScript).
      oSheet.Range("A2", "B6").Value = CreateNamesArray();

// Fill C2:C6 with a relative formula (=A2 & " " & B2).
      var oRng = oSheet.Range("C2", "C6");
      oRng.Formula = "=A2 & \" \" & B2";

// Fill D2:D6 with a formula(=RAND()*100000) and apply format.
      oRng = oSheet.Range("D2", "D6");
      oRng.Formula = "=RAND()*100000";
      oRng.NumberFormat = "$0.00";

// AutoFit columns A:D.
      oRng = oSheet.Range("A1", "D1");
      oRng.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

// Manipulate a variable number of columns for Quarterly Sales Data.
      DispalyQuarterlySales(oSheet);

// Make sure Excel is visible and give the user control
   // of Excel's lifetime.
      oXL.Visible = true;
      oXL.UserControl = true;
}

function DispalyQuarterlySales(oWS)
{
      var iNumQtrs, sMsg, iRet;

// Number of quarters to display data for.
      iNumQtrs = 4;

// Starting at E1, fill headers for the number of columns selected.
      var oResizeRange = oWS.Range("E1", "E1").Resize(1,iNumQtrs);
      oResizeRange.Formula = "=\"Q\" & COLUMN()-4 & CHAR(10) & \"Sales\"";

// Change the Orientation and WrapText properties for the headers.
      oResizeRange.Orientation = 38;
      oResizeRange.WrapText = true;

// Fill the interior color of the headers.
      oResizeRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 36;

// Fill the columns with a formula and apply a number format.
      oResizeRange = oWS.Range("E2", "E6").Resize(5,iNumQtrs);
      oResizeRange.Formula = "=RAND()*100";
      oResizeRange.NumberFormat = "$0.00";

// Apply borders to the Sales data and headers.
      oResizeRange = oWS.Range("E1", "E6").Resize(6,iNumQtrs);
      oResizeRange.Borders.Weight = 2;  // xlThin

// Add a Totals formula for the sales data and apply a border.
      oResizeRange = oWS.Range("E8", "E8").Resize(1,iNumQtrs);
      oResizeRange.Formula = "=SUM(E2:E6)";
    // 9 = xlEdgeBottom      
      oResizeRange.Borders(9).LineStyle = -4119; //xlDouble
      oResizeRange.Borders(9).Weight = 4; //xlThick

// Add a Chart for the selected data.

oResizeRange = oWS.Range("E2:E6").Resize(5,iNumQtrs);
      var oChart = oWS.Parent.Charts.Add();
      oChart.ChartWizard(oResizeRange, -4100, null, 2);  // -4100 = xl3dColumn
      oChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = oWS.Range("A2", "A6");
      for (iRet = 1; iRet <= iNumQtrs; iRet++) {
         oChart.SeriesCollection(iRet).Name = "=\"Q" + iRet + "\"";
      }
      oChart.Location(2, oWS.Name); // 2 = xlLocationAsObject

// Move the chart so as not to cover your data.
      oWS.Shapes("Chart 1").Top = oWS.Rows(10).Top;
      oWS.Shapes("Chart 1").Left = oWS.Columns(2).Left;
}
</SCRIPT>
<P><INPUT id=button1 type=button value="Start Excel" 
          onclick="AutomateExcel"></P>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Save the file to a directory of your choice with the file name Excelaut.htm.

Close Notepad and start Internet Explorer.

In the Address bar, type C:*path*\excelaut.htm, where path is the directory you saved the file in.

When Internet Explorer loads the file, you'll see one sentence with a button. When you press the button, Excel will start on the client's machine and fill with data.

Doing that makes a web page with a button.  Doesn't do anything in any browser.

Comment: "Doesn't do anything in any browser." well it could only ever work in IE because other browsers do not support ActiveX/COM, and even then it would only work with security set at a dangerously low level.  If you wanted to do something like this then you'd likely need to use an HTA (dated but does still work...)  e.g. https://analystcave.com/vbs-hta-example-for-vba-developers/

Comment: IE doesn't do anything either when tried.

Comment: Like I noted you would first need to go into Internet Options and set your security setting to a super-low level for it to work.   Definitely not recommended.

Comment: Tried that too, didn't help.

Comment: Did you check for errors in the Developer tools console?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a text file with an `.hta` file extension and open it.
It's just a brief demo showing how to open Excel from an HTA.
Should work assuming you're not on a Mac.

```
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
 <title>XLS Data Demo</title>
 
    <hta:application
        applicationname="XLS Data"    
        border="dialog"
        borderstyle="normal"
        caption="Test"
        contextmenu="yes"
        icon=""
        maximizebutton="yes"
        minimizebutton="yes"
        navigable="no"
        scroll="no"
        selection="yes"
        showintaskbar="yes"
        singleinstance="yes"
        sysmenu="yes"
        version="1.0"
        windowstate="normal"
    >
 </head>
 <body>
 Press the button to start Excel and display quarterly data.
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JScript"> 
    function AutomateExcel()
    {
        alert("starting excel...");
        /* Start Excel and get Application object. */
        
        var oXL = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
        oXL.Visible = true;
        var oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add();
        var oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet;
        oSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "First Name";
        oSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Last Name";
        oSheet.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Full Name";
        oSheet.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Salary";
    }
</SCRIPT>
<P><INPUT id=button1 type=button value="Start Excel" 
          onclick="AutomateExcel()"></P>
 </body>
</html>
```